# Supplying the model with varying amounts of data from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, oop, model

Supposed I have an online store and a model **User**, which contains a whole bunch of parameters (First Name, Last Name, an Address object, ProductCategoryAccess object etc.)

The way it's currently set up is the constructor accepts an Id and populates the entire class with data from the database.

But what if I don't need all that data?  For example, if I have a view that just lists users, I'd have to create a list of Users, with each of them needlessly querying the database for information that I don't need (Address, ProductCategoryAccess, etc).

What's the best way of handling this?  Do I create a bunch of different classes, with only the parameters I need for various situations?  Do I create one User class, but with different "setter" methods, which will use different queries to populate only certain parameters?

Comment: I would tend to favor both. You repository could have a method `List<EmployeeItem> FetchEmployees()` which populates a collection of `EmployeeItem` containing only `ID` and `Name` properties for displaying in a list (Index view) and a method `Employee Get(int ID)` that returns `Employee` that includes all properties for displaying in a details or edit view. The advantage is it gives you strongly typed models that relate to your views. And `Employee` can inherit from `EmployeeItem` so minimal extra code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using any ORM tools to get the data? If yes, then you could use lazy binding to retrieve only elements that you need.

If you are directly querying the db, then dividing it across different methods with queries should do the trick.

What are the different situations you need to account for?

Comment: Directly querying the db.  As far as the different situations, it could be for editing the user (needing most of the model), only showing user names (to show a list of registered users), only needing to know if a user is an admin, only needing the user's product category access restrictions, etc

Comment: You put me on the right track with lazy loading.  Turns out you don't need to be using an ORM for that. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/652556/Can-you-explain-Lazy-Loading

Answer (score 0):

If you only wish to select certain properties from your user database record then you can use projections to bind the records into a data transfer object that contains only the properties you need for any given page.

For instance, if you needed properties for an edit user page then your query (I assume you're using Entity Framework?) would look something like this:

```
this.userContext.Users.Where(y => y.UserId == userId).Select(x => new UserEditDto {
    FirstName = x.FirstName,
    Surname = x.Surname,
    EmailAddress = x.EmailAddress
}).FirstOrDefault();
```

What this will do is build a LINQ query against the database that selects only the properties specified within the `select` part of the LINQ statements. In fact, if you were to remove the `FirstOfDefault()` method and stick a breakpoint in you'd be able to see the SQL generated by that statement would look a little something like:

```
SELECT FirstName, Surname, EmailAddress FROM users WHERE userId = 1;
```

It's only when you call `.FirstOrDefault()` does the LINQ provider execute the query against the database and return the result.

From here you're able to return your DTO to your service layer or your controller to send it to a view within a view model. You can then rinse and repeat this same type of query for other possible data transfer objects and views that require certain data.

Comment: I'm actually not using EF.